# Python - Detect type of private key (rsa/dsa/ecc)

Tags: python, pycryptodome

I have many private keys in a format looking like this:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I would like to remove the passphrase from these keys using the python `PyCryptodome` lib. I do know the passphrase.
However, I do not know the key type of each key (They are a mix of RSA/DSA/ECC keys).

Is there any way to detect the key type, so that I can use the correct procedure to import/export the key?
(e.g. `Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.import_key`
, `Crypto.PublicKey.ECC.import_key`)

Currently, I'm doing this, which is rather ugly:

```
try:
    rsa_key_decrypted = RSA.import_key(key, key_passphrase)
    decrypted_key = rsa_key_decrypted.export_key(pkcs=8).decode('ascii')
except:
    try:
        dsa_key_decrypted = DSA.import_key(key, key_passphrase)
        decrypted_key = dsa_key_decrypted.export_key().decode('ascii')
    except:
        ecc_key_decrypted = ECC.import_key(key, key_passphrase)
        decrypted_key = ecc_key_decrypted.export_key(format='PEM')
```

Comment: Decode them using the first algorithm, then try the next one if that fails. Repeat until you find the correct one.

Comment: @Selcuk That's what I'm currently doing (see edit). However, that is rather ugly and I'd love a more straight-forward solution.

Comment: Nope, that's the way.